# Activerecord map to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I'm trying to take everything out of my Users table and send it to mail chimp for subscription.

I need to go from `User.all` to

```
[{:email => {:email => "example@domain.org"}, 
  :merge_vars => {:FNAME => "First name", :LNAME => "Last name"}
}]
```

I'm trying to do this with `map` but I'm struggling, any ideas of the *cleanest* way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subscription_array = User.all.collect do |user| 
 {
  :email => {:email => user.email}, 
  :merge_vars => {:FNAME => user.first_name, :LNAME => user.last_name}
 }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
users_array = []
User.all.find_each {|u| users_array << {:email => u.email, :merge_vars => {:FNAME => u.first_name, :LNAME => u.last_name} }
```

I chose to use find_each is it's a more efficient way of loading your collection.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html